# Error on homepage of local server no changes made since last working?

Tags: cache, error

I have just gone back to a site I am working on locally to continue working on it. 2 days ago it was working fine and I have made no changes. I now have this error when I load the homepage.

unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 24 bytes

C:\Websites\website\craft\app\framework\caching\CCache.php(108)

Anyone have any idea why this has happened and how to fix it as I say nothing had changed with the files or with the MAMP install.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have resolved this by deleting all the cache files in the craft|storage|runtime|cache folder. But whilst this has worked my question is now why did it happen. Not something I want to experience on a live site?

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure your Cache option is set to OFF in MAMP > Preferences > PHP. I think it defaults to OPCache which can cause problems with local development if it set to on.